# How Can You Exclude Categories From Your RSS Feeds?

Tags: categories, rss

I've searched and found posts that have asked and answered how to merge different categories into an RSS feed. **What I need to know is how to exclude specific categories from the RSS feed?**

Specifically, I use WP to post blog articles and to post portfolio items onto my site.  I want to exclude the portfolio category from appearing in the RSS feed, making only blog posts available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been broken since 3.1, see:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16622
and also
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-31-breaks-rss-customization-via-exclude_category
**NOTE:** Otto's suggested fix in that thread doesn't work for me.

Ticket suggests patch will go in for 3.1.1 and i can confirm that currently filters on `pre_get_posts` or `parse_query` fail for feeds(unfortunately).

Comment: @t3los - in the thread you listed there is a plugin that may do the trick for now (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/).  I'm planning on giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Not too confident to get hooks right from memory... I think hooking into [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and setting [`category__not_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) to what you want to skip on [`is_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) conditional should work.

But might require playing with different hooks earlier/later, querying internals are confusing around there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpsites_exclude_category_rss_feed($query) {
 if ($query->is_feed) {
   $query->set('cat','-007,-008');
 }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpsites_exclude_category_rss_feed');
```

Either of these snippets in your functions file will work using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
function wpsites_exclude_category_rss_feed($query) {
if ( $query->is_feed) {
    $query-> set('category__not_in',array(007));
    }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpsites_exclude_category_rss_feed');
```